# Solidify Modifier: how can I remove the inner mesh in a complex artifacts?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices

First of all I want to specify my final goal: **use the Solidify Modifier in order to create a cage**.

I think that my workflow, used since now,

- Duplicate my low poly
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> with the new mesh (i.e. cage)

isn't the way to achieve the best result, because it creates too much distorsion and doesn't preserve the original shape of my low poly, in particular with hard surfaces' meshes.

Therefore I found the solidify modifier that works pretty well. There's only one problem that i will show you with an easy example:

1) This is my High Poly

[image]

2) This is my Low Poly

[image]

I duplicate my Low poly and then with my new mesh (cage) I apply the Solidify Modifier in order to cover my high poly. The problem is that the solidify modifier double the mesh. In the final result i have my low poly, high poly and **the cage, with 2 "meshes" (not divided, they are still a unique mesh in the Outliner)** one inside the other like in the image below.

[image]

**How can i delete the inner mesh?**

**In a simple mesh could be easy, like this cube, but when i have complex artifacts?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly but I think you may be misunderstanding what the *Solidify* modifier does.

It creates thickness on an object by duplication it's faces and offsetting the  by a specified distance along its normals. This makes it two sided, and creates a new set of faces virtually "duplicating" your object.

That being said you may use it for what you want by activating the options *Fill Rim* and *Only Rim*, that way only the distorted "cage" will be created, and no duplicates will be found.

[image: Solidify Rim Only]

**Edit**

See an example of an open area bellow where additional faces are created.

Have you tried the *Smooth* modifier instead? It wont create additional faces, and will have a similar offset effect, though it may cause some distortion in tighter corners.

[image: Smooth Modifier]

**Edit 2**

Apparently the user's problem was with selecting linked geometry in edit mode.
You could apply the *Solidify* modifier with the *Fill Rim* option unchecked, and then enter edit mode and either hover one of the unwanted vertex and press <kbd>L</kbd> or select one of the unwanted vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to *Select Linked*

[image]

Comment: Already used this trick. The problem here is this: checking "Fill rim", it adds vertices to my cage (in blender there is written: "Create Edge loops"). I'm creating a complex mesh with multiple smoothign groups etc . . and i want to have the same amount of vertices for my low poy and the cage. I can't tick it

Comment: Yes, I see, if you have single sided parts in your mesh then it will create a border around them. Could you isolate those parts into a separate object so that you could use a different technique on them?

Comment: I really don't know ^^. In my mesh i can't distinguish them onestly. On 2000 vertices, using the method you tell me, the difference between low poly and cage is 20 vertices. It's hard to find them

Comment: Edited my answer above. Have you tried the Smooth modifier instead? It wont create additional faces but may cause some distortion.

Comment: Yeah already used but as you said it causes deformation. It is similar to the classic alt+s

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas then, maybe someone else smarter than me can chime in with better ideas, or you'll probably have to do it manually

Comment: @Fuboski, I dont understand why you have to check "fill rim" ?

Comment: I don't want to check it . . . @DuarteFarrajotaRamos advises me, cause it's the only way to actice "only rim" and remove the inner mesh automatically. My goal is to remove the inner mesh without using "fill rim"      ---> "only rim" beacuse this trick add unwanted vertices.

Comment: @Fuboski so do we agree that you will obtain two separated parts if you dont check "fill rim" at all ? Is that not enough in your problem ?

Comment: These 2 parts won't be separated at all, doesn't matter "fill rim" checked or not. The problem is that i would like to understand if there is a simple and quick method to separate these 2 parts and then delete the inner one; because when you applied the modifier, these 2 part, although don't share vertices, edge or faces, are a unique mesh like i said in the question.

Comment: Have you tried after applying and entering edit mode pressing L to select linked geometry? They are one and the same object but should be two separate chunks of mesh altogether.

Comment: @Fuboski, +1 for what Duarte just said (but Ctrl+L)

Comment: @Fuboski or eventually "separate by loose parts" : select all in edit mode, then P

Comment: Yeah it works @DuarteFarrajotaRamos!! Thank you so much! If you edit your quesion with the new answer i'll tick it as solved, in order to close this thread Thank you again

Comment: Answer above updated, and image added.